How to extract all <div> tag contents of a specific class name from HTML using regular expressions in Python?
I'm writing a crawler in Python that needs to extract the content of all <div> tags with a specific class name (e.g. "class-name") from an HTML document. I've learned that regular expressions are usually not the best tool for parsing HTML because it can fail due to the complexity and nested structure of HTML. However, in this particular case, the HTML structure is relatively simple and predictable, so I would like to try using regular expressions for this task. I have tried the following code, but it does not seem to work as expected:
My question is:
Is my regular expression correct? If there is an error, how should it be modified to ensure that it only captures the content of<div>tags with the class name "class name"?
If regular expressions are indeed not the best way to handle this situation, can you recommend a more suitable Python library (such as BeautifulSoup) to handle this problem and provide a brief example code?

The re.DOTALL flag is used to make the . character match any character including newlines.

The re.IGNORECASE flag is optional but can be useful if you're not sure about the case sensitivity of the class name.

This regex assumes that there are no nested <div> tags with the same class name inside the target <div> tags. Nested tags can break this regex.

HTML attributes can be in any order, and there can be additional attributes or whitespace, which can make regex solutions fragile.


    import re  

    html_content = """  
    <html>  
    <body>  
        <div class="unwanted-class">Don't want this content</div>  
        <div class="class-name">Need this content</div>  
        <div class="class-name">Also need this content</div>  
    </body>  
    </html>  
    """  

    pattern = r'<div class="class-name">(.*?)</div>'  
    matches = re.findall(pattern, html_content, re.DOTALL)  

    for match in matches:  
        print(match.strip())  





You are correct that something like BeautifulSoup would be a much more robust solution than attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions. The documentation is full of examples of how to use that module (and there a many answers here on stackoverflow on the same topic).

You can use [^>]* patterns that match anything that is not a closing > before and after the desired class-name to allow other attributes within the <div> tag:
import re

html_content = """  
<html>  
<body>  
    <div class="unwanted-class">Not wanted</div>  
    <div class="class-name">Wanted1</div>  
    <div class="class-name" data-id="1">Wanted2</div>  
    <div style="color:red;" class="class-name">Wanted3</div>
</body>  
</html>  
"""

pattern = r'<div\s+[^>]*class="class-name"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>'
matches = re.findall(pattern, html_content, re.DOTALL)

for match in matches:
    print(match.strip())

Output:
Wanted1
Wanted2
Wanted3

To allow other classes with class-name you can use a pattern like "[^"]*\bclass-name\b[^"]*" to allow other class names to be present as well. \b word boundary is to match “class-name” as a whole word:
pattern = r'<div\s+[^>]*class="[^"]*\bclass-name\b[^"]*"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>'

Use BeautifulSoup
As mentioned, using regex is not recommended for parsing HTML. A better approach is to use a library like BeautifulSoup:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = """  
<html>  
<body>  
    <div class="unwanted-class">Not wanted</div>  
    <div class="class-name">Wanted1</div>  
    <div class="class-name" data-id="1">Wanted2</div>  
    <div style="color:red;" class="class-name">Wanted3</div>
</body>  
</html>  
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="class-name")

for div in divs:
    print(div.get_text(strip=True))

Output:
Wanted1
Wanted2
Wanted3

